# Checking to see if a mailbox is on a specifc database (syntax error!)

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I would like to check $true or $false if a user is in a specific mailboxdatabase.
This doesn't work:

```
if((get-mailbox user| select Database) -eq "server\group\dbgroup") {
   echo $true
} else {
   echo $false
}
```

(returns False)

But

```
get-mailbox user | select Database
```

returns

```
Database
--------
server\group\dbgroup
```

How do I check for this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Christian already gave you the answer, but to answer you "syntax error".
When you pipe to Select-Object you get back an object with the properties you specified: Database.
To access the property you need to call it, so in order for your code to work you'd have to write it this way:

```
if((get-mailbox user| select Database).Database -eq "server\group\dbgroup") {
   echo $true
} else {
   echo $false
}
```

Comment: Really weird. I can do this approach on any other cmdlet, but for some reason this doesn't work on get-mailbox.. The return is multilined so I cannot do a -EQ on it..

Comment: Database is an object on its own so you may get its properties when print it, I tested it at work and it worked for me. I can't test it now, what happens if you do: (...).Database.ToString() -eq "server..."

Comment: Yes that worked Shay! Thank you! I am running Exchange 2007 btw.. That may be the reason. Thanks again:)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this (can't test it):

```
if( (get-mailbox user).Database -eq "server\group\dbgroup")
```